# LMER: specify interaction between main fixed effect and nested random effect

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I have an experiment where I tested the influence of mycorrhizal fungi on plant growth, in six populations of a plant species. Each population had 10 maternal lines (families, Fam) in it. I'm interested in the main effects of fungi (Myco: 2 levels) and population (Pop: 6 levels), the random effect of family (nested in population), and the potential for variance in response to the fungi among families nested within each population. Is this the correct model specification in `lmer`?

```
lmer(biomass ~ Pop * Myco + (1|Pop:Fam) + (1|Myco:Pop:Fam), data = fungiExp)
```

If I find, via LRT, that the `(1|Myco:Pop:NewFam)` term significantly improves the model, would I be correct in saying, "the effect of mycorrhizal fungi on biomass production varies among families (within at least one population)"?

Comment: Yes, but I would replace your random terms (both) with `(Myco|Pop:Fam)`, and compare it with `(1|Pop:Fam)` only.

Comment: @amoeba thx! so two followup questions:
1. can you elucidate the distinction between `(Myco|Pop:Fam)` and `(1|Myco:Pop:Fam)`? My understanding is the former would estimate among family variance in biomass, and also estimate variance explained by, instead of varying the intercept randomly, varying it with respect to Myco level. 
2. if I compare the two models you specified via LRT and specifying the `Myco` intercept doesn't improve the model, would you say that there is no among family variance in response to Myco?

Comment: (0) Note on terminology: what you call "among family" I would call "between family". (1) These two are probably equivalent models (but I am not 100% sure). That's because your `Myco` is binary; if it had more levels then it would be different models. I suggested to write it as `(Myco|Fam)` because I think it's easier to understand. It says: the effect of `Myco` can depend on `Fam`. Which is what you want to model and to test. `(Myco|Fam)` equals `(1+Myco|Fam)` so it includes the random intercept. (c2) Yes. But apart from LRT, you can also look at the estimated variance itself.

Comment: @amoeba (0) interesting -- I use among whenever there are more than two objects being compared, but maybe I should review my use of the word! (1) the model terms come out similar but not identical -- I'll update my question (or answer) with this info.